# Ruby not selecting from the right table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Workout` model:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :exercise

  belongs_to :session
  has_many :exercise_equipment

end
```

and an `Exercise` model

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts
end
```

and in my `show` I have `@workout.exercise.name` which throws an `SQLException:`

```
no such column: exercises.exercise_id: SELECT  "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."exercise_id" = ? LIMIT 1
```

Despite reading some similar posts, I truly cannot understand why the `has_one :exercise` line results in `SELECT exercises FROM exercises`  This doesn't seem to make any sense, I would assume that because I'm using a `Workout` object that it would check in the `workouts` table for my

**I've tried**

```
has_one :exercise, :class_name => 'Workout', :foreign_key => 'exercise_id'
```

But then I get `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

```
add_foreign_key :workouts, :exercises
add_foreign_key :exercises, :workouts
```

No luck, Buck.

So could some one kindly explain to me what Ruby/Rails thinks it's doing here and how I can avoid this confusing issue in the future?

**tables**

```
exercises
    id:integer
    name:text
    description:text
    created_at:text
    updated_at:text

workouts
    id:integer
    name:text
    exercise_id:integer
    session_id:integer
    created_at:text
    updated_at:text
```

Comment: If you have a has_one or has_many on Workout, there must be a workout_id on the referenced association.  The association model would have a `belongs_to :workout`

Comment: An exercise exists independent of a workout though.  I should be able to have a 'Jumping Jack' exercise without ever having to say whose workouts reference that exercise, right?  So I'm still not sure why it's trying to select the exercise_id from the exercise table.

Comment: Does one workout have many exercises?  Or just one?

Comment: For now, I am keeping it to one exercise per Workout.  Later I will add a many relationship, but I feel I should get this working first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to change this on Workout

```
has_one :exercise
```

To

```
belongs_to :exercise
```

The `belongs_to` goes with the table that has the foreign_key on it.

Comment: This works, but I have a few questions.  Is it ok to have two belongs_to relationships like this?  Does this mean that for has_many and has_ones, you do not need to provide a foreign key?

Comment: Yes you can - the `belongs_to` really just gives you a bunch of methods that expect the foreign key to be on the object.  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to  You will have as many belongs_to as you have foreign keys in the db.  `has_one` is rare.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify foreign keys in Ruby if their name is *entity_id*. If you want to have N Workouts for one Exercise all you have to do is to have column *exercise_id* in your *workouts* table and then specify your models:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :exercise
end

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts
end
```

Comment: I mistyped my models, I have tried them exactly like this.  It does not work.

Comment: Can you update models and add database schema to your original post?